# How to say in that year 2000

Tags: grammar

Which of this following  expressions is right if i want to say that year 2000. Besides is necessary a , in any of both expressions.

2000年那年   or   2000 那年

It is supposed to be used in sentences such as “2000年那年，姚明获得了成功。” or “2000那年，姚明获得了成功。”

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Comment: 2000年那年，姚明获得了成功。   Or.  2000那年，姚明获得了成功。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 2000年那年，姚明获得了成功。√
- 2000那年，姚明获得了成功。×

Answer (score 2):

`那年` means `that year`, which is a pronoun and could be used in the sentences afterwards.

e.g.   
`In 2020, sth happened. balabal. In that year, other things happened.`
`在2000年，发生了什么什么。在那年，还发生了其他什么。`

Answer (score 1):

I would go with “在2000年，姚明获得了成功。”